# Creating an instance double with a stubbed out attr_writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to stub out Ruby's `Net::HTTP`'s `use_ssl=` attr_writer method. How do I do that?

```
let(:http) { instance_double("Net::HTTP", use_ssl=: true) }
```

does not work. How do I do this? I want to use an instance double because it preserves actual method arity and makes sure the method exists.

Also what's the best way to stub out this environment variable in a spec?

```
domain = ENV['SERVICE_HOST']
```

Comment: It looks like you could stub the getter method [instead](https://github.com/sj26/ruby-1.9.3-p0/blob/master/lib/net/http.rb#L661). Would that serve your purpose?

Comment: It has a question mark at the end... this seems like the same problem no?

Answer (score 0):

To stub the `use_ssl?` method, you could do:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Net::HTTP).to receive(:use_ssl?).and_return(true)
```

In a similar manner, to stub out an ENV variable, you can do:

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with("SERVICE_HOST").and_return("my_host")
```